# Flutter project gives error in ios: Framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, simulator

Recently, my project stop working in iOS device or simulator! I tried every possible solution like:

```
rm -fr ios/Pods/; rm -fr ios/Runner.xcworkspace/; rm -fr ios/Podfile.lock;
flutter clean; flutter pub get; flutter run;
```

Unfortunately the error still there. I searched in Google and here in
Stackoverflow but I didn't find any solution.

This is the error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           19.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/1t/4_2zr9_90gb_n3bmdbb6d84h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.SRezAB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDsUt3l/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    ld: framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Mantle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'SDWebImageWebPCoder' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/khalid/Projects/diwan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/1t/4_2zr9_90gb_n3bmdbb6d84h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.SRezAB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirDsUt3l/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): Framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
Exited
```

This is my flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm, locale en-SA)
    • Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at /Users/khalid/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (8 days ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/khalid/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14B47b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64 • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • iPhone 14 (mobile)          • A850C08F-D439-47AE-B1B2-0CA29261A4F1 • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-1
      (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                • darwin-arm64  • macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Any help will be appreciated,
thank you in advance.

Comment: I just update all my packages, but the error still appear!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it by removing these two lines:

```
"-framework",
"\"FirebaseCoreDiagnostics\"",
```

everywhere from this file:
ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj